# TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I test my code:

```
def read_classification_from_file(path, name):
        path = add_slash(path) + name
        myfile = open(path, "r")
        mydict = {}
        for line in myfile():
                x = line.split(" ")
                x[1]=x[1].replace("\n","")
                mydict[x[0]]=x[1]
        return mydict
def add_slash(path):
        if path.endswith('/'): return path
        return path + '/'
```

I receive error :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "spamfilter/solution/test_quality_for_corpus.py", line 59, in test_allPredictionsHam
    q = self.compute_quality_for_corpus(CORPUS_DIR)
    File "/local/ulohy/env/data/4893_1/quality.py", line 9, in compute_quality_for_corpus
    truth_dic = utils.read_classification_from_file(corpus_dir, "!truth.txt")
    File "/local/ulohy/env/data/4893_1/utils.py", line 5, in read_classification_from_file
    for line in myfile():
    TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable
```

So, I just font understand, where the error is.

Thank you!

Comment: "_where the error is_": It's shown right there in traceback - `for line in myfile():`

Comment: Its not my error, but UnitTest. So, sorry. Please, delete topic

Comment: you can delete it yourself, but clicking delete link

Comment: Sorry, this ques. has answer and can not be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want `for line in myfile:`.  `file` objects can be iterated over directly (yielding 1 line at a time).  However, file objects don't support calling (e.g. `myfile()` isn't implemented because `file.__call__` isn't implemented).